# How to (safely) remove Ubuntu from Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

In case anyone is still reading this, I finally figured it out.

Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). Scroll down to the box that says "Noncommercial" and click register. You can enter your email, or use one at [10 Minute Mail](https://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/). After you've installed it, click the "BCD Backup/Repair" tab. Click the second option, Re-create/repair boot files, and hit Perform Action. Screenshot: i.imgur.com/9Bb3awL.png. It'll load for a few seconds and then disappear.

Restart your computer, and the GRUB screen should be gone. Boot back into Windows

Now you'll need to get rid of the extra partition space. Click the start button (Windows button in bottom left-hand corner) and right click the 'Computer' option on the right side panel. Select 'Manage' under the drop down menu. Computer Management should open up. Several partitions will be listed.

Two of these will be from Linux and the third will be Windows'. The two Linux ones will be white with no title. Right click both and select 'Delete' on the drop down menu. A popup will appear saying that the partition is used by another operating system and that it will be effected. Click Okay. Once you do this there will be a green square that says "X GB Free space". Right click it and select "Delete partition" on the drop down menu. Now the box is unallocated space. You'll need to extend the Windows partition to utilize this space. This time right click the **Windows OS** partition (not the unallocated space) and select "Extend Volume". A screen will be brought up; just click yes and skip through the menus and the Finish button.

Now the box should change to reflect that this space is now apart of Windows. You can double check by going to the start menu and clicking 'Computer' on the right. Your C: should now include that space.

Hopefully this helps someone out there. Credit goes to Jeremy Matthews' "How To: Remove Ubuntu from a Dual Boot Computer" video.

Note: This won't affect anything (files, etc.) currently on your Windows system. Backup anything of importance on Linux, though.

This method also doesn't require an installation CD, since I was getting continually frustrated that everything was saying that I needed one to fix it (I don't even own one).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't have to install Ubuntu to boot into your computer.  You need to install a Boot Manager to boot into your computer.

When you installed Ubuntu, you installed Grub.  Grub is a boot manager that allows you to boot Windows or Linux.

You used a Linux installer.  You can **use a Windows installer** to install the Windows boot manager instead of using a Linux installer.

Once you install the Windows boot manager, you can again, delete the Ubuntu partition(s).  You won't see a trace of Linux at that point.

Comment: Additionally, you can boot from some live media with a partitioning tool and regrow the Windows partition.